# How to write a double edge in an incidence matrix.

Tags: graph-theory

In Linear Algebra, Geodesy, and GPS
 By Gilbert Strang,Kai Borre

It is said that it is allowed but they don't define it. Thus I was wondering how to write an incidence matrix when there is the double edges case, for instance in this case:[image: graph with one double edge situation]

Do the relation give a 1, a -1 or a zero in the incidence matrix for[9-11][11-9]. I feel it is a zero as far as 1 and -1 seems to be used only when it is oriented in one direction.

Comment: Usually it would be just a pair of ordinary edges with opposite directions, i.e. $(9,11)$ and $(11,9)$.

Comment: Yes but I'm in the case where it is only one edge. it represents a two way street.

Comment: In what way is that different in your case?

Comment: No, it's okay, I understood your point. I replaced the column representing this edge in my incidence matrix by two columns and it made perfect sense, thanks!

Comment: ? An edge isn't represented by a column in an adjacency matrix, but by a cell.